# QuickFIX: log rotation feature

Tags: quickfix

It seems QuickFIX has not log rotation feature.
Is it possible to do it somehow?

Answer (score 2):

[This post shows the rotation might have been released longtime ago.](http://old.nabble.com/Log-rotation-td16858177r0.html) There mayn't be any config change to be made, maybe you need to implement it yourself as described in the post.

[Here it explains that it isn't possible to rotate without shutting down your engine.](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.finance.quickfix.devel/3737) Your engine would have the old hook to the logfile and when it sees that the log file doesn't exist, probably would crash. In the same post it explains that divide your multiple seesions for each day, 7 logs for 7 dys in the week. Should be a plausible method to do it, when you shouldn't be restarting your engine in the middle of a day.